# Car detection with openCV using android

Tags: java, android, c++, opencv

I'm developing an application that detects and counts the cars.

my problem: I can not recognize the car, I can count them but if for example a person has passed her too.

How do I recognize the car? 
Also, if it passes a bus or large middle has more than one, how can I solve this?
I hope I was clear 
Franki

Comment: you might want to read some books about object detection/classification/recognition.

Answer (score 2):

You're using simple bounding rectangles.

```
Rect rect = Imgproc.boundingRect(points);
```

It will detect **any** kind of object large enough to fit the criteria, so naturally - also people.

As a simple solution i suggest measuring rect.height and rect.width - a car would usually be a lot wider that higher, while a regular person is usually higher that wider.

Since the approach is very basic, you can only process basic features, so there is very little you can do.

Alternatively you could pre-process the image and figure out the color blobs using openCV - a car would be usually a large wide, not very high object of the same average color.

**UPDATE:** According to the OpenCV4Android project the sample includes the Color blob detection sample [OpenCV4Android samples description](http://opencv.org/platforms/android/opencv4android-samples.html). It's under *Sample – color-blob-detection*

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice, could you explain better about the pre-process the image? 
I can't use another method instead of the rectangle?
thanks again

Comment: @Franki Please check my updates for the sample of color blob detection.